# AngularJS input with number get undefined when out of range

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to validate custom input box as following

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputNetwork" class="control-label">{{'DNS_PRIMARY' | translate}}</label>
<div class="control-content">
    <p>
        <input type="number" integer min="1" max="223"
            class="ip-single-column" ng-model="network.dnsPrimary[0]" name="dnsP0" required ng-blur="dnsBlur('P', 0)"
            ng-class="{'has-error': networkForm.dnsP0.$invalid}" validate-dns>.
        <input type="number" integer min="0" max="255"
            class="ip-single-column" ng-model="network.dnsPrimary[1]" name="dnsP1" required ng-blur="dnsBlur('P', 1)"
            ng-class="{'has-error': networkForm.dnsP1.$invalid}" validate-dns>.
        <input type="number" integer min="0" max="255"
            class="ip-single-column" ng-model="network.dnsPrimary[2]" name="dnsP2" required ng-blur="dnsBlur('P', 2)"
            ng-class="{'has-error': networkForm.dnsP2.$invalid}" validate-dns>.
        <input type="number" integer min="0" max="254"
            class="ip-single-column" ng-model="network.dnsPrimary[3]" name="dnsP3" required ng-blur="dnsBlur('P', 3)"
            ng-class="{'has-error': networkForm.dnsP3.$invalid}" validate-dns>
    </p> 
</div>
```

```
       $scope.dnsBlur= function(section, pos) {

        var elem = $scope.network.dnsPrimary;
        var i = pos;
        if(section.endsWith('P')) { 
            // primary
            switch(i) {
                case 0:
                    if (angular.isUndefined(elem[i]) || (elem[i] < 1 && elem[i] > 223))
                        elem[i] = $scope.defaultDns[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // if (!elem[i] || (elem[i] < 0 && elem[i] > 254))
                    if (angular.isUndefined(elem[i]) || (elem[i] < 0 && elem[i] > 254))
                        elem[i] = $scope.defaultDns[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (angular.isUndefined(elem[i]) || (elem[i] < 0 && elem[i] > 255))
                        elem[i] = $scope.defaultDns[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (angular.isUndefined(elem[i]) || (elem[i] < 0 && elem[i] > 254))
                        elem[i] = $scope.defaultDns[i];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }




}]).directive('validateDns', ['$rootScope',
function($rootScope) {
    function link($scope, elem, attrs, c) {
        $scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            c.$setValidity('outOfRange', true);


            switch(c.$name.charAt(c.$name.length - 1)) {
                case 0:
                    if (!$scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] || ($scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] < 1 && $scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] > 223))
                        c.$setValidity('outOfRange', false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (!$scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] || ($scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] < 0 && $scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] > 255))
                        c.$setValidity('outOfRange', false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (!$scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] || ($scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] < 0 && $scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] > 255))
                        c.$setValidity('outOfRange', false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (!$scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] || ($scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] < 0 && $scope.network.dnsPrimary[i] > 254))
                        c.$setValidity('outOfRange', false);
                    break;
            }

        });
    }
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };
}
```

But when I trying to get input number in Blur() function.

It will get undefined when the input out or range. For example, input 999 but get undefined.
Is it anyway to get 999 in Blur()?

Comment: `validate-ip` is a directive that you wrote? can you add it so we can see what it does?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in Blur or in the others decorators in there. The value of the field should be the actual value otherwise even if it is out of the specified range.

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="console.log(this.quantity.value);return false;">
  Quantity:
  <input type="number" name="quantity"
   min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30" onblur="console.log(this.value);">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: update my original questino snippet. I have try your code it works. when I add `onblur=console.log(this.value)` it also works in my code. but when I change it to ng-blur it doesn't work. even if I add `network.dnsPrimary[i]` into dnsBlur function.

Comment: My guess is that the validate function makes the input value invalid on ng-  directives.

Comment: I would go with a validation per field `validate-dns-segment` and a validation per model which would be valid on all segments are valid.

Comment: Because I have to implement it when primary DNS is empty will auto adjust to 0~255.
and for secondary DNS will keep it empty. So, I need to check the value of input. But in ng-blur I get undefined when it out of range or empty.

Cound you give a brief sample of validation you are talk about? Thanks.

Comment: use ngSubmit for validation, maybe

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at here [Angular ng-model changes to undefined when checkbox on ng-repeat has the required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156272/angular-ng-model-changes-to-undefined-when-checkbox-on-ng-repeat-has-the-require)

But need AngularJS after 1.3.

I am using AngularJs 1.2. So, I need to find another way out.